# How do I create a SQL Server Express database at runtime in a C# MVC App?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I'm trying to do this using Entity Framework 5 in C# in an MVC3 web application:

```
// Local DB connection
var dbId = String.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}.mdf;Database=Tests;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", _dbPath);
_connection = new SqlConnection(dbId);

Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());

// Reset database if the file exists
var ctx = new MyContext(_connection);
ctx.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
ctx.SaveChanges();

return _connection;
```

This works for my tests, but not when I run the web application. When I run the web application, I get:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)*

I see in a few other questions people have suggested removing the 'User Instance' from the connection string, but that results in:

> *CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.*

Let me be entirely clear on my goal here: I'm trying to have the web application create database instances (`sqlexpress`) on demand.

Creating the database instances *in advance* is not a solution.

I'm quite puzzled about why some kind of special permission is needed when the app worker is the one accessing *and creating* the database.

How can you do this?

Using sqlite this is a trivial operation, and I'm starting to feel like using Entity Framework (and thus SQL Server Express) was mistake and I should have gone with fluent nhibernate and sqlite instead.

Comment: Are you using IIS to host your MVC app? If so, what account is the app pool using. It is possibly a permissions issue on this account.

Comment: Yes. On my local copy of IIS I'm using the "ASP.NET v4.0" worker; this hasn't gone anywhere near production, obviously, because its broken, but we have a separate worker for the application on prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980 suggests that it is a file permission issue for the default account of the "ASP.Net V4.0" App pool, "ApplicationPoolIdentity" and suggests changing it to use "Network Service" instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to help. Changed to use the "NetworkService" identity, ran iisreset, and still I see: "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

Comment: I take that previous comment back; after restarting the machine, this did actually fix it! iisreset isn't sufficient on its own; perhaps something about restarting sql server was also involved, but a full restart fixed it.